# Shortest path connecting multiple nodes in iGraph R

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I have an iGraph network in R and would like to find the shortest path connecting multiple nodes in my network (let's say nodes 1,3,4,7). Is there a function that can do that? Something like `all_simple_paths` but for one global solution?

The solution should look something like the path highlighted in yellow. Note that 1->2->4 is not selected even though it is just as short as 1->3->4.

```
library(igraph)
tree <- graph.tree(n = 8, children = 2, mode = "out")
tree <- add_edges(tree, c(3,4, 3,5))
plot(tree)
```

[image]

Comment: @MrFlick no, I just added an example to show you. `shortest_paths` gives a separate solution for each destination rather than one global solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging I think I found the answer to my own question. What I was describing is a variation of the minimum spanning tree problem called the **Steiner tree problem**.

> Given a weighted graph G = (V, E), a subset S ⊆ V of the vertices, and a root r ∈ V , we want to find a minimum weight tree which connects all the vertices in S to r. [[ref]](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture10.pdf)

Turns out there is a R package called `SteinerNet` created specifically for these types of problems. I had trouble installing their package directly but was able to copy the relevant source code from their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cran/SteinerNet/blob/master/R/steinertree.R).

```
out <- steinertree(type = "KB", terminals = c(1,3,4,7), graph = tree)
```

The package does exactly what I wanted to do, and it even produced a pretty graph!

```
>out[[2]]
IGRAPH fbb52e5 UN-- 4 3 -- Tree
+ attr: name (g/c), children (g/n), mode (g/c), name (v/c), color (v/c)
+ edges from fbb52e5 (vertex names):
[3] 1--3 3--4 3--7
>plot(out[[1]])
```

[image: Output from SteinerNet function]